# Fixing "You may not export a method of a subclass of js.Any"

Tags: scala.js

I am trying to create a binding based on typescript type information to a Javascript library (underscore) for Scala.js. It contains some methods like the following:

```js
/**
* Create a shallow-copied clone of the object.
* Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.
* @param object Object to clone.
* @return Copy of `object`.
**/
clone<T>(object: T): T;
```

The problem is, when I try to translate this to Scala.js:

```
@JSExport("clone")
def cloneJS[T](`object`: T): T = js.native
```

I get the following error:

> You may not export a method of a subclass of js.Any

(Similar things happen when I tried to do the same with a [`toString()`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a6e165ec11d827fe22550c9af868b29e67b9e5b7/underscore/underscore.d.ts#L3368) method.)

Is it safe to skip translating these methods as Scala can handle them or there is a way to fix this method implementation?

(I am using Scala.js 0.6.3.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@JSExport` (and related annotations) are designed to export methods and properties of Scala objects to JavaScript. Here, you are defining an interface for a JavaScript object for use by Scala.js, so exporting doesn't mean anything.

I see you're trying to give a different name with the annotation. For that purpose, in facade types, there is another annotation: `@JSName`. So the proper definition of your method should be:

```
@JSName("clone")
def cloneJS[T](`object`: T): T = js.native
```

and everything will be fine.

Btw, in this instance, nothing prevents from defining the Scala method with the name `clone` in the first place (since there is one argument, it will be different from the `Object.clone()` method):

```
def clone[T](`object`: T): T = js.native
```

will work just as well, and will probably be nicer at call site.